# How to create a div, below a given div, on top of others, but without changing positions of others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create a div, just below a given div but on top of all other divs in the page without moving their position?  Here is an example:

```
  ---------------------------------------------
  |               |          |                |
  |    div1       |   div2   |         div3   |
  |               |          |                |
  ---------------------------------------------
  |                     |                     |
  |    div4             |         div5        |
  |                     |                     |    
  ---------------------------------------------
  |... some more divs...
```

I want to create a div, in div2's onClick handler, so that when div2 is clicked on, the newly created div will be displayed which is left aligned to div2, is below div2 but is on top of other divs below.  The new appearance of the page will be:

```
  ---------------------------------------------
  |               |          |                |
  |    div1       |   div2   |         div3   |
  |               |          |                |
  ---------------------------------------------
  |               |                  |        |
  |    div4       |     Newly        |  div5  |
  |               |     Created      |        | 
  -----------------     Div          ----------
  | ...some more..|                  |        | 
  |  ...divs...   |                  |        | 
  |               |                  |        | 
  |               |                  |        | 
  |               |                  |        | 
  ---------------------------------------------
```

The solution must be generic. The Javascript function will, for example, be:

```
 createDivBelow(css selector, height, width)
```

So, given the css selector of any div, the function will create a div below it, left aligned and of the specified height and width. The critical issue is that it must be positioned so that other divs below or elsewhere are not moved.  The newly created div must be on top.  I figured that the new div must be absolutely positioned, possibly with respect to body. But how to know where to position it? Afterall, div2 itself may be embedded in other divs.

**EDIT to address some of the comments and proposed soutions**
I need a generic solution, oblivious to the structure of the page. The solution must not be aware of other elements, let alone depend on the CSS of other elements and div2 itself may be placed anywhere.

Comment: Which element should be the parent of the newly created div ? Please share the hierarchical view of the DOM tree. No need the share the actual HTML code, think of a files and folders structure.

Comment: Please show us some code...also what do you mean by `The newly created div must be on top`..?

Comment: Posted a theoretical answer. If you add a code sample to your question, notify me and I'll update my answer with the same.

Comment: @LFSon I have not reviewed all the answers, will do now. The key problem is that the rest of the HTML is assumed to be unknown. I mean this is supposed to be a generic function that assumes nothing. What parent if any? What are the positions of the parent or grandparents or whatever... Only the positioning of  div2 can be assumed to be NOT absolute.  If the structure (CSS, etc) of the rest of the HTML is known or can be controlled, then the solution is easy.

Comment: @Bhuvan please see my comment.

Comment: @Sam The _updated_ solution I suggest, doesn't care about the html structure, it will only position that newly created `div` left/bottom aligned relative to the `div` clicked at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated based on a comment by the OP*

Theoretically you do like this:

1. when a `div` is clicked, add a class to it, which set its position to other than `static`, e.g. `position: relative`, and `z-index` to a value greater than the rest of the `div`'s, and it will be on-top
2. append the newly created `div` to the clicked one, give it an absolute position, set its `left` to `0` and its `top` to `100%`, and it will be positioned left/bottom aligned, w/o any other elements moving, and no matter which `div` is clicked.

With the above, it will also be responsive, and if the user change screen width, this will move along.

---

Here is a simple demo.

Stack snippet

```js
$("nav div").click(function () {

  $(this).toggleClass('haspopup');

  if ($(this).hasClass('haspopup')) { 
     $(this).append("<div class='popup'>Here is your popup</div>");
  } else {
     $(this).find('.popup').remove();
  }
  
});
```

```css
nav {
margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  counter-reset: demo;
}
nav div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
nav > div::before {
  content: 'DIV';
}
nav + div {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav div.haspopup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
nav div.haspopup .popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</nav>

<div>This element won't move or be affected when the popup shows</div>
```

Comment: I will test a few cases and will respond shortly. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that CSS reset is not an issue. You are changing only position and z-index which gets reset on class toggling. Rest CSS stays.  The question I have is rather elementary:  You say "append the newly created div to the clicked one."  You mean  append to body?  Please give a simple example code and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Sam Updated my answer with a sample

Comment: @Sam Here is what I mean by "you'll have to reset inherited styles" : https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49585322/6. Hope this is clear enough now. I admit that this is not a big issue though.

Comment: @leaf I rolled back your update, but got that, and am sure OP did to. And when it comes to menu/sub-menu solutions, you often actually want exactly that to happen, but of course, if one does not, those styles need to be reset...or one simply add one more child inside the `div` and style that one. IMHO, either way ought to be better than e.g. listen to a script event, do you agree with that?

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks for taking the time to think of it.

Comment: @leaf Btw, next time you want to show such issue, don't edit someone's answer, copy it to e.g. a fiddle, and link to it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to make a navigation bar. Blind shot :

```js
$("nav div").click(function () {
  if ($(this).data("menu")) {
    $(this).data("menu").remove();
    $(this).removeData("menu")
  } else {
    var t = this.offsetTop;
    var l = this.offsetLeft;
    var h = this.offsetHeight;
    $(this).data("menu",
      $("<div class=\"menu\">menu</div>")
      .appendTo(document.body)
      .css({ "left": l, "top": t + h})
    );
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em; /* test */
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav div {
  width: 100px;
}
main div {
  width: 150px;
}
.menu {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav><div>div 1</div><div>div 2</div><div>div 3</div></nav>
<main><div>div 4</div><div>div 5</div><main>
```

Comment: Yes you are right... this is part of a navigation bar plugin. The key  problem is that the solution must be generic without any reference to the rest of the HTML's structure. I did upvote your answer because you understood the application of the issue which I should have mentioned...

Comment: @Sam It's still unclear to me. What's wrong with my JS code currently ? There is no reference to the rest of the HTML structure. Please elaborate a little :-)

Comment: I will test a few test cases and will respond shortly. It appears that your solution and LGSon's are on similar lines.

Comment: @Sam I think so. Code updated to make it a little more generic (`#menu2 -> .menu` and `.data()`). Now you can click any of the nav divs.

Comment: The down side with this is it is not responsive, as when the element are dynamically sized, and a user change orientation or viewport width, this won't work, unless you start listen to the resize event.

Comment: @Sam LGSon's answer does not require updates on resize, this is probably easier to manage.

Comment: @LGSon Your solution requires CSS reset for inherited styles though, it can be hard to manage.

Comment: @leaf No, there is no such issues what so ever, simply toggle a class back and forth.

Comment: @LGSon Yes there is, think of it twice :-)

Comment: @leaf I think LGSon is right.  The solution changes only position and z-index which is handled by the toggling of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".child").click(function(){        
        createDivBelow($(this), "150px", "150px");
    });
});
function createDivBelow(cssSelector,height,width){
        $(".newchild").show();
        $(".newchild").css({"left":cssSelector.position().left+"px"});
        $(".newchild").css({"top":(cssSelector.position().top+cssSelector.height())+"px"});
        $(".newchild").css({"height":height});
        $(".newchild").css({"width":width});
}
```

```css
.parent{
width:100%;
}

.child{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
.newchild{
  position:absolute;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:none;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
  <div class="child">div4</div>
  <div class="child">div5</div>
  <div class="child">div6</div> 
  <div class="child">div7</div>
  <div class="newchild">Newly created div</div>
</div>
```